# Linked Lists - Insert elements at the back of the list

Tags: c++

I want to write a program that inserts elements of the back of the list. I have the following C++ program:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct node {
   int val;
   node * next;
} node;

int main() {
   node * head = NULL;
   int i, v[100];
   for (i=1; i<=5; i++)
   {
       cin >> v[i];
   }
   for(i=1;i<=5;i++) 
   {
       node *temp1=new node;                         
       temp1 = head;                 
       while(temp1->next!=NULL) 
           temp1 = temp1->next;
       node *temp=new node;                          
       temp->val = v[i];                  
       temp->next = NULL;                  
       temp1->next = temp;
   }
   while(head) {
      cout << head->val << " ";
      head = head->next ;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

The problem is that everytime I compile it, it gives segmentation fault error and I don't understand why. Any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: head is never initialized.

Comment: Your first two lines in the second for-loop are an instant-memory leak and contributory to you problem as well.

Comment: @YuchenZhong depends on your definition of "initialized". It certainly has an initial value (`node * head = NULL; `).

Comment: @WhozCraig. Yes, you are right :)

Comment: If you are creating your own linked-list implementation, you should consider using a sentry node. see http://pastebin.com/egDECvDi

Comment: or consider learning how to [forward-chain using a pointer-to-pointer](http://ideone.com/RNAHla) (which by-circumstance means you need to study more about pointers).

Answer (score 0):

By the time you access `temp1->next` in your `while(temp1->next!=NULL)` loop, `temp1` is already `NULL`due to the `temp1=head` assignment, causing the segmentation fault.